# files in the root of a jekyll theme not copying over to where that theme is used

Tags: jekyll, service-worker, github-pages

I have a jekyll theme (https://github.com/godalming123/matirlize-jekyll-theme) and I use it in (https://github.com/godalming123/blog) however in the jekyll theme I have a service worker located in the root of the theme with

```
---
---
```

at the begining.
However this `./sw.js` file does not appear in the github pages site for https://github.com/godalming123/blog
Help would be appreciated many thanks

Comment: are you sure it is not working? It will not appear in the blog repo because it is a remote theme. But it should work remotely.

Comment: Would it be of any deference that I am using the remote theme gem

Comment: Yes, the theme files will not be present at your blog's directory since the theme is remote. you can fork the remote theme and use the fork as the remote theme, that way you can clone the theme to your machine and modify it if you want.

Comment: But I already maintain the remote theme on my github